# Tkinter Alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still trying to figure out Tkinter and I don't understand why this `right` variable doesn't show up all the way to the right? I thought these frames would divide the window vertically, no?

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root, bg = 'blue').grid(row = 0, column =0,sticky = W)
Label(frame1, text = 'Left').grid(row = 0, column =0,sticky = W)

frame2 = Frame(root, bg = 'blue').grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = E)
Label(frame2, text = 'Right').grid(row = 0, column =1,sticky = E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you draw a picture that shows what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: as [Paul Cornelius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985899/7032856) points out your `frame1` and `frame2` is assigned to `None`, rather than objects of Frame widgets as they both are results of a method, that has no `return`,

Answer (score 2):

Nae's answer is correct but it didn't quite work when I tried it.  The reason is that

```
frame1 = Frame(root, bg = 'blue').grid(row = 0, column =0,sticky = W)
```

binds the name `frame1` to the returned value of .grid(), which is None.  When you execute this line:

```
Label(frame1, text = 'Left').grid(row = 0, column =0,sticky = W)
```

you are, in effect, making the label a top-level window because its parent is None rather than the Frame.

This worked for me (python3.6 on Windows 10):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root, bg = 'blue')
frame1.grid(row = 0, column =0, sticky = W)
Label(frame1, text = 'Left').grid(row = 0, column = 0)

frame2 = Frame(root, bg = 'green')
frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 1,sticky = E)
Label(frame2, text = 'Right').grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

To elaborate on the explanation of columnconfigure: by default, tk squeezes the grid into the minimum possible space, even if that doesn't fill the window.  So the two labels end up squeezed to the left.  Even though the second one has sticky=E, there's no extra space in the layout so you don't see the effect of the sticky setting.  You override this by assigning a non-zero weight to one or more columns.  That tells tk to expand the grid until it fills the window by allocating the unused space based on the relative column weights.

Comment: I see - thank you. So I should always break up the .grid() from the initial frame declaration. Really like Tkinter just such a steep learning curve (at least for me). Thanks!

Comment: _"you are, in effect, making the label a top-level window"_ - your terminology is a bit confusing here. You aren't making it a _window_, nor a "toplevel". The code simply makes the widget a child of the root window.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)
```

just before

```
root.mainloop()
```

optionally you can add the below alone for some reason:

```
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
```

I think the reason your code doesn't seem to work as you wanted is somehow root window refusing to shrink it's width more than that. If you have longer texts or larger fonts it works as you intended it to.

Comment: thanks! Perfect...I've tried understanding what this column configure does, but I can't get it to click. Would you have a good way of explaining what it does exactly?

Comment: @user6142489 I think it tells (parent, columnNumber, weight) tells the grid to resize itself with a factor of weight if its parent is resized, which in your case root has a longer row than needed but by default weight=0 so it doesn't care for resizing. rowconfigure works in a similar way.